# How to align two form fields on the same row in html page using css?

Tags: css, forms, css-float, styling, border-box

I have this html text

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="glossary-form"></div>

<div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block; width:48%;padding-right: 5%;">
  <label for="glossary_entry_input_1">Lemma IT</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_1" placeholder="">              
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block; width:48%; padding-left: 5%;">
  <label for="glossary_entry_input_2">Lemma CH</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_2" placeholder="">              
</div>

<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="glossary_entry_input_3">Acronimo IT</label>
                    <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Inserire una sigla (se esiste) del Lemma. Nel caso in cui il lemma sia una grandezza fisica, inserire la lettera o il simbolo che la identifica.</small>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_3" placeholder="">              
            </div>  

</div>
```

generating the following form fields, aligned on one line, as you see

[image]

and I want to display them symmetrically to the vertical axys of my html page, by moving the second one to the right, as you see

[image]

So that the left margin of the "Lemma CH" box is aligned with the one of "Acronimo IT" box.
How do I have to change my code to obtain the result shown in the second image?

Comment: your using bootstrap so please use bootstrap grid based on your requirement

Comment: In the second picture, the "Lemma CH" box is moved a little more to the right so that its right margin is the same of the  "Acronimo IT" box below.

Comment: Please create a working snippet we will be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Sumit Patel. I added the working snippet.

Comment: @Tms91 I give an answer. Check it. It may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float right is not a right solution. try this.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="glossary-form"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="glossary_entry_input_1">Lemma IT</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_1" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="glossary_entry_input_2">Lemma CH</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_2" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="glossary_entry_input_3">Acronimo IT</label>
      <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Inserire una sigla (se esiste) del Lemma. Nel caso in cui il
        lemma sia una grandezza fisica, inserire la lettera o il simbolo che la identifica.</small>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_3" placeholder="">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask you to remove the line containing "favicon" please? just because i don't want anyone to reconduct my work to this question. thanks. Also thanks for your help, I upvoted your question

Comment: actually this answer does not solve my problem because i see that the two lemma boxes are displayed one below the other, while i need them horizontally aligned.

Comment: That because you are checking in small screen please view snippet in Full page and you will see. in smaller device bootstrap will make it 100%. float right is not a good solution.

your problem in here is you are not using bootstrap grid, which provide you more control over the DOM and as we all know bootstrap is best for responsive.

Comment: You are right. Sorry I already put my green check before, the other guy was just quicker

Comment: Just FYI if you feel other answer better you can change answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution. I've added following code to "Lemma CH" box. Hope it will meet your requirement.

```
float: right;
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="glossary-form"></div>

<div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block; width:48%;padding-right: 5%;">
  <label for="glossary_entry_input_1">Lemma IT</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_1" placeholder="">              
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block; width:48%; padding-left: 5%; float: right;">
  <label for="glossary_entry_input_2">Lemma CH</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_2" placeholder="">              
</div>

<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="glossary_entry_input_3">Acronimo IT</label>
                    <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Inserire una sigla (se esiste) del Lemma. Nel caso in cui il lemma sia una grandezza fisica, inserire la lettera o il simbolo che la identifica.</small>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="glossary_entry_input_3" placeholder="">              
            </div>  

</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what is was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can I ask you to remove the line containing "favicon" please? just because i don't want anyone to reconduct my work to this question. thanks.

Comment: Of course @Tms91 . I just removed it. Actually I didn't notice that earlier. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use their documentation..

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row

I'd advise using bootstrap docs as you are using bootstrap anyway. Creating the form how you are will require further CSS to cater for responsive design. Use the docs and bootstrap will look after you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will look for responsive design next time

Comment: No problem, @Sumit Patel answer is the best as he has used bootstrap grid...

This means whilst only using bootstrap classes (no inline CSS) you have achieved exactly what you asked and also is it out of the box responsive with no additional CSS...

The answer you have accepted will result in further code to again cater for responsive design. Since you are already using bootstrap to create the web page then there is no reason not to use it and get more familiar with it.